# Enquiry for Visa UK

Tags: uk

How should I answer ‘Have you been refused a visa for any country including the UK?’ knowing that I was refused last year in the usa embassy. EDIT: I don’t know the refusal reason so my question is how do I explain that in the application?

Answer (score 1):

You would have been verbally advised of the reason(s) at the time of the decision. If you can’t remember what it was, contact the relevant U.S. Consulate and discuss what happened and ask them to tell you whether or not declining to issue a visa constitutes an actual denial of a visa. If they will provide it, ask for written confirmation.

Comment: because they ased me in the application about the reason of refusal and they don’t tell me the reason in the u.s embassy.

Comment: @A.A Then you need to ask how to answer the question about the reason of refusal, not about being refused a visa.

Comment: okay shall you please tell me the answer ?

Comment: @a.a you can contact the place where you were refused and ask them. That's what Traveller recommended above. We can't know what the reason was.